# How can I make a join table with Django models?

Tags: database, django, django-models

I'm a beginner bumbling through a Django guide and it told me to put this in models.py:

```
class Bookmark(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    bookmarks = models.ManyToManyField(Bookmark)
```

This should make a join table with this SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "bookmarks_tag_bookmarks" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "tag_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "bookmarks_tag" ("id"),
    "bookmark_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "bookmarks_bookmark" ("id"),
    UNIQUE ("tag_id", "bookmark_id")
);
```

But when I run manage.py sql bookmarks, I instead get this SQL:

```
 CREATE TABLE "bookmarks_tag_bookmarks" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "tag_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "bookmark_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "bookmarks_bookmark" ("id"),
    UNIQUE ("tag_id", "bookmark_id")
);
```

The join table doesn't reference the tag table. Could anyone please explain to me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look further down the output of ./manage.py sql.  I suspect you'll see a line like:

```
ALTER TABLE "bookmarks_tag_bookmarks" ADD CONSTRAINT "tag_id_refs_id_somehash" FOREIGN KEY ("tag_id") REFERENCES "bookmarks_bookmark" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't get anything like that. The SQL I posted is the only thing that mentions the bookmarks_tag_bookmarks table.

Comment: You should, I've never seen it do anything that wrong.  It very wel could be at the very bottom or much lower.  It's an order of operations issue the tags table needs to exist and the sql generator has created the join table before both of the tables so it adds the constraints later.  You should be able to confirm this completely by running syncdb and then going into the db and checking the schema

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense. The SQL output shows that the join table is created before the tag table. So it's possible that the database is correct, but the SQL output it's showing me is misleading?

Comment: I found that Django makes a function called tag_set(). I tried out that function and it appears to work, so that must mean that the database is correct even though the SQL output wasn't. It's a bit rubbish that I can't actually look at the database since it just gives me something incorrect, but good to know the database is working. Thank you for everything.